# Print contents of array using DOM

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to print the contents of an array using innerhtml. Printing it in a `<p>` tag. When the array is greater than 1, nothing is printed. What am I missing?

```
function printInv() {
var print = "";
for (var i = 0; i < playerInv.length; i++) {
    print += "<br>" + test[i].name;
}
}
if(playerInv.length >= 1) {
    document.getElementById('display-inv').innerHTML = printInv();
}
```

Comment: You forgot to return `print`.

Comment: I think `return`

Answer (score 3):

> When the array is greater than 1, nothing is printed. What am I
>   missing?

I guess **return value**

```
function printInv() 
{
   var print = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < playerInv.length; i++) 
   {
      print += "<br>" + test[i].name;
   }
   return print; //this line
}
```

Simpler version

```
function printInv() 
{
   return playerInv.map( function( v, i ){ return test[i].name }).join( "<br>" );
}
```

**DEMO**

```js
var playerInv = [1,2];
var test = [ {name: "name1" }, {name: "name2" } ];
if (playerInv.length >= 1) 
{
  document.getElementById('display-inv').innerHTML = printInv();
}
function printInv() 
{
  return playerInv.map(function(v, i) {
    return test[i].name
  }).join("<br>");
}
```

```html
<div id="display-inv"></div>
```

Comment: Still getting nothing printed

Comment: Works when i run your test array, but not with my own array

Comment: You haven't shared your array yet, so how could we know?

Comment: Nothing more than: var playerInv = [];

Comment: @Znowman There's nothing in your array, and you're asking us why the result is nothing???

Comment: Alright, so the page has to update when objects are added or they wont print?

Answer (score 0):

Your printInv function returns nothing you need to add `return print;` at the end

Comment: Doesnt print anything, says undefined in the <p> tag